# Importing Redmine wiki into Atlassian Confluence

Tags: wiki, redmine, confluence

We are migrating from Redmine to the product suite of Atlassian.

We successfully migrated the tickets from Redmine into Jira + Jenkins data into Bamboo.
The only thing I'm not able to import is the wiki data from Redmine into confluence.

Does anyone have/know a solution for this.  (Manual import is not an option => +1500 pages)

Grtz & thanks Ilias

Comment: I don't see a project to do the import. However, Redmine wiki source is much like any wiki source: it uses typographical conventions to map to hypertext conventions. Using Perl (my personal favourite language) or Python, or even Ruby, to translate the wiki text would be straightforward. Where you would have difficulties is all the resource referencing: bringing in attached documents and links to issues in Jira. There you would need an import protocol and mapping database.

Comment: Hire a couple interns, imho. They're great at manually converting huge quantities of tedious stuff.

Answer (score 2):

[This is a solution](https://github.com/vile/redmine2confluence-wiki) we have come up with recently. There are two scripts, first allows you to prepare data for conversion by exporting wikis and attachments. Second can push (almost) everything into confluence wiki, keeping links, most of the tables. 
It is not perfect, so DO expect some reasonable damage to content.